# Lighting panel for switches

Tags: electrical

I would like to create a panel for 13 switches, for a small shop area in one location, that will switch lights and outlets on and off for different applications.

I've been told to use the breaker panel but would rather not because of location as well as having access to all the breakers versus just the ones I want to switch off daily, I.E. Lights.

It could be visible but would prefer it to be behind a small access door as 13 switches would look bad for sure.

Comment: So what is the specific question. How to build a recessed niche and panel cover and install 13 switches inside ?

Comment: Why not break the lighting circuits out into a subpanel at the appropriate spot?

Comment: On this side of the pond I would agree a sub panel makes sense with breakers that are rated as switch duty. Running 13 different circuits to switches and the boxes to contain this just sounds like a mess where a sub would be clean and less expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use **the** breaker panel.   Use **a new** breaker panel in a location of your choosing.

You'll need 4 wires from the existing breaker panel to the new one.  You'll need 2 *spaces* for a 2-pole breaker in the existing panel.  If protective devices like GFCI are required, those can be part of that 2-pole breaker.

Then, you basically use the new breaker panel as a switch bank.

Naturally, it can double as a proper breaker panel. You'll need to put 20A breakers or 15A as appropriate to protect your various branch wiring and devices.  If you have call for a 30A piece of equipment, you can do that too. 240V, not a problem - you'll have both legs.

Also the breaker panel will make it *ridiculously easy* to add additional new circuits as the need arises -- **provided you use an extra large panel** with spaces to spare. Because spaces are cheap and regrets are expensive, we very strongly recommend to "Go Big Big Big" when selecting a panel. Finishing the project with half the spaces unused is a good sign you sized the panel properly.

If AFCI/GFCI requirements allow, you can also use ["double-stuff" breakers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwihgIDgpPXoAhVZCs0KHZn9CIIQFjAAegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdiy.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F110151%2Fwhat-is-a-tandem-breaker-aka-duplex-cheater-twin-double-stuff-etc&usg=AOvVaw3LXYvhAn9FGjmR_TcSNCuP) as an aesthetic choice to remind yourself which breakers are lights and which are receps.

If you are switching HID lighting (mercury vapor, metal halide, low/high pressure sodium), or old school fluorescents with 5-pound ballasts, then you must use "HID" rated breakers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state your location, but in the UK *grid switches* are widely used.

https://www.electricaldirect.co.uk/product/mk-18-gang-metalclad-grid-front-plate-grey-759111

Grid switches comprise a frame and a faceplate, to which a variety of switches, indicator neons, fuses, and other accessories can be fitted to form one assembly. They are commonly used in commercial wiring (as switches with ratings up to 20A are available, whereas UK lighting switches are often only rated at 5A and require derating for inductive/fluorescent loads).

The flat grid faceplate (without accessories fitted) facilitates engraving. Individually-engraved switches with common legends (heating, lighting, fan, etc) are also available.

When fitting grid switches, attention should be paid to any rules about multiple circuits or different phases within the same enclosure.

[image: 18 gang grid switch faceplate - three rows of six switches]

Comment: You have enough reputation points to know that the best answers are ones that **explain how to do the advice given in the answer**. Short, one link, answers get down voted or removed.

Comment: Meanwhile, in 'Murica, we have Despard and Decora triple switches. and gang-boxes as many as 6-gang.  So there's your 18 switches.  However since OP entails 13 separate circuits, which is going to create a simply staggering amount of box fill.  Won't get that in a 6-gang box.